# Regex to fetch offset c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a 3 example strings (Timezones) and I want to fetch the (offset) of theirs.

1. `GMT-05:00 Eastern Time(Toronto)`
2. `(GMT - 06:00) Central Time(US, Canada)`
3. `GMT-10:00 Hawaii - Aleutian Standard Time(Honolulu)`

I want the above strings answers to be like :

1. `-05:00`
2. `-06:00`
3. `-10:00`

I have a regex `[^0-9-:+]` which gives out the desired answers for the first and second example but for the third it results out as `-10:00-`

Please help me out building an required Regex to fetch the offset.

Comment: Javascript? C#? Qt? Which language are you  using?

Comment: I am using c# @Toto

Comment: Do those strings follow some kind of pattern? Or are just "random" and impredictable from user input?

Answer (score 2):

Try regex `[+-]?\s?\d{2}:\d{2}` to match optional sign and then two decimal sequences

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/ZrYapw/2)

Comment: won't match the second as there is a whitespace before the 06

Comment: @Greedo Oh, it's part of group... Lol. Fixed

Comment: With this regex i get the output for the first and third in desired manner!
But for second its coming as 06:00 the - is getting ignored

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
\bGMT\s*([-+]?)\s*(\d+:\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbGMT%5cs*%28%5b-%2b%5d%3f%29%5cs*%28%5cd%2b%3a%5cd%2b%29&i=GMT-05%3a00+Eastern+Time%28Toronto%29%0d%0a%28GMT+-+06%3a00%29+Central+Time%28US%2c+Canada%29%0d%0aGMT-10%3a00+Hawaii+-+Aleutian+Standard+Time%28Honolulu%29).  Details:

- `\bGMT` - a whole word `GMT`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([-+]?)` - Group 1: an optional `-` or `+`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+:\d+)` - 1+ digits, `:`, 1+ digits.

Then, you need to concat two groups to get the final value:

```
var strs = new String[] {"GMT-05:00 Eastern Time(Toronto)","(GMT - 06:00) Central Time(US, Canada)","GMT-10:00 Hawaii - Aleutian Standard Time(Honolulu)"};
foreach (var s in strs)
{
    var result = Regex.Match(s, @"\bGMT\s*([-+]?)\s*(\d+:\d+)");
    if (result.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Parsing '{s}'\nResult: {result.Groups[1].Value}{result.Groups[2].Value}");
    }
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/0KRZS0), output:

```
Parsing 'GMT-05:00 Eastern Time(Toronto)'
Result: -05:00
Parsing '(GMT - 06:00) Central Time(US, Canada)'
Result: -06:00
Parsing 'GMT-10:00 Hawaii - Aleutian Standard Time(Honolulu)'
Result: -10:00
```

Answer (score -2):

this regex will get you the expected result:

`[\+|-]?\s*\d+:\d+`

Also, it considers the possible whitespaces

[Examples](https://regex101.com/r/RK61jY/2)

Comment: you should use [] instead of ()  .. () means group -> `[+-]?\s*\d+:\d+`

Comment: It should be `\d`, not `d`. Also `+` does not need to be escaped

Comment: right, was corrected in the link but not in the answer